Looking for a textbook on logic
I'm preparing an introduction to logic for non-mathematicians, and in the process, I’m trying to better understand the basics myself. I came across a post on this forum: Difference between $\to$, $\models$ and $\implies$, where a textbook is mentioned but not directly referenced.
In the post, @MauroALLEGRANZA provided an answer, also citing the textbook, but to my knowledge, it was not referenced.
I was wondering: Which textbook is this question and the corresponding answer based on?
Thank you!

Dirk van Dalen's Logic and Structure. There is also a more recent edition.

You'll have the ask the OP from that question. The thing is: one logic texbook can use one symbol to formalize some logical concept, but a different textbook can use a different symbol for that same concept. And even more confusingly, two different textbooks can use the same symbol, but it means something different between the two textbooks.

@MauroALLEGRANZA: Thank you! I had doubts about whether this was the right textbook, as the references don't seem to match your answer. Additionally, I couldn't locate the quote mentioned in the question within the textbook you referred to.
Apologies for any inconvenience—I'm just trying to clarify the distinction for myself.

Ideally this Query should have been a comment to the given earlier Post , where the concerned users could have replied to make that Post more complete there. I think that this Post can be deleted.

Based on the available information in the question, I recommend a textbook called Beginning Mathematical Logic: A Study Guide by Peter Smith.
This textbook is incredible for a first introduction to logic, for mathematicians and non-mathematicians alike. The reason that I think it will be particularly useful for you is that it has lots of recommendations for further reading in the various chapters. Therefore, its many textbook recommendations for the price of one.

Well, strictly speaking BML is not a textbook on mathematical logic but rather a guide to other textbooks --- but the recommendations there (and elsewhere on my website) may help you find what you want. You can freely download BML from https:logicmatters.net/tyl.
